# Access denied to all users after migrating site to new server

Tags: users

Please don't consider this as a duplicate post. I have tried all the solutions that worked for others, but still struggling to fix the problem (all users including admin taken to 403 page). This is a Windows server running Drupal 7.

Things I have tried -

- No base_url value given
- No cookie_domain value given
- Session table truncated
- Cache tables truncated
- No file permission differences
- Tried Reset password email but the link takes to 403 page
- Deleted browser cache

Please let me know if anyone has experience with a similar issue or what else I could try.

This is what I can see in watchdog table.
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out!

We are enforcing secure flag on our cookie and therefore had to disable the corresponding rewrite rule from IIS, as we didn't have a SSL certificate in new server.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user table in the DB. sometimes when importing DBs it starts auto-numbering from 1, so you don't have a user with the id of 0, which Drupal uses for its anonymous user.